# python pandas data frame create columns if list of string contained in one columns

Tags: python, pandas, string, search, match

given this df:

```
data = {'Description':  ['with milk and orange', 'champagne', 'BANANA', 'bananas and apple', 'fafsa Lemons', 'GIN LEMON'],
        'Amount': ['10', '20', '10', '5', '9', '15']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print (df)
```

and the following vector:

```
Fruits = ['apple','banana','lemon', 'orange']
```

how to obtain the column 'Fruit'? (search for all the elements of the vector Fruits in the column description and add them in the Column 'fruit' if contained in Description)

```
datanew = {'Description':  ['with milk and orange', 'champagne', 'BANANA', 'bananas and apple', 'fafsa Lemons', 'GIN LEMON'],
        'Amount': ['10', '20', '10', '5', '9', '15'],
        'Fruit':  ['orange', '', 'banana', 'banana-apple', 'lemon', 'lemon'],
       
       }
df2 = pd.DataFrame(datanew)
print (df2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another way by using `str.findall()`

```
(df.assign(Fruit = df['Description'].str.lower()
.str.findall('|'.join(Fruits))
.str.join('-')))

            Description Amount         Fruit
0  with milk and orange     10        orange
1             champagne     20              
2                BANANA     10        banana
3     bananas and apple      5  banana-apple
4          fafsa Lemons      9         lemon
5             GIN LEMON     15         lemon
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) and [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.aggregate.html):

```
import re
df['Fruit'] = (df['Description']
               .str.extractall(f"({'|'.join(Fruits)})", flags=re.I)
               .groupby(level=0).agg('-'.join)[0]
               .str.lower()
              )
```

output:

```
            Description Amount         Fruit
0  with milk and orange     10        orange
1             champagne     20           NaN
2                BANANA     10        banana
3     bananas and apple      5  banana-apple
4          fafsa Lemons      9         lemon
5             GIN LEMON     15         lemon
```